# How to efficiently perform operations on a String which acts as a timer in Java

Tags: java, string

This question has been bugging me for quite some time now. Suppose I have a batch of strings in the form of: "hh:mm:ss,ms" where ms = milliseconds. I want to have a method like so:

```
public void shift(String toShift, int byHowMuch)
{
    // code here
}
```

that will increment/decrement the value of the string by a certain amount of milliseconds. If the second argument is a positive integer, its value in milliseconds gets added to the string. Conversely, if it's a negative integer, its value gets subtracted from the string.  For example, if:

```
String toShift = "00:00:01,500";
```

and we call:

```
shift(toShift, 500);
```

then the value of toShift will be "00:00:02,000". Next, if we call:

```
shift(toShift, -500);
```

the value of toShift will change back to "00:00:01,500".

So, my question is: From a mathematical standpoint, what is the best way to implement this method, i.e. how can I minimize the amount of 'ifs' and checks in it?

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: The best way is to not use String

Comment: You don't need any if-s and else-s if you convert each component of the string toShift into a number, add byHowMuch to it, then convert the result back to a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you cannot perform the change in place. You are going to make a new object anyway. The simplest and the most robust approach is to have no `if`s at all:

- Parse the string into an integer representing the number of milliseconds,
- Add `shift` to the result,
- Format the number as a sequence of digits, colons and commas.

You may need to add a few checks to ensure that the `int` result fits in the allocated number of digits.

Comment: And AFAIK, Java has methods for formatting integers representing time into something human-readable.

Comment: You're right. I feel so incredibly stupid right now.